# Find difference between two rows on insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table that stores readings from devices in the form of

| deviceId | timestamp | value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | 5 | null |
| 1 | T2 | 8 | 3 |
| 1 | T3 | 10 | 2 |

Since `value` is a counter that keeps increasing, I need to have a delta value to find out the actual rate (i.e. difference between the values of Tn+1 - Tn)

Is there any **efficient** way to calculate the delta on each insert for a device id?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to materialize it; in this case `LAG()` will compute it easily on a query. If you want to materialize it, then a trigger can do the trick. However, it'll need to handle concurrency if more than one thread is inserting simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be not efficient , you can calcuate it anytime you need that data , It's not really necessary to be materialized in the table :

```
select * , value - LAG(value , 1, 0) over (partition by deviceid order by timestamp) delta
from tablename
```